Python namespace with unused attribute detection
I want to refactor some constants so they share namespace in a Python project. Something like this:
class MyNamespace():
    """ Does NOT need to be a class, this is just an example. """
    AVOID_MAGIC_NUMBER: int = 10
    SOME_TEXT_OUTPUT_MESSAGE: str = 'something'
    FREQUENTLY_USED_INIT_ARG: str = 'magic initialization argument'
    THIS_IS_A_WELL_KNOWN_FILENAME: Path = Path('some_hardcoded_filename.txt')
    BASE_FILENAME: PATH = THIS_IS_A_WELL_KNOWN_FILENAME.stem
    HERE_IS_AN_OBJECT = DefinedElsewhere(FREQUENTLY_USED_INIT_ARG)

The fact that they are not real constants is not an issue. My needs:

A namespace, so the variable names do not clash with imported symbols, locals, etc.
Some of the attributes need to refer to previously defined attributes, sometimes.
If some attribute stops being used in the code, the IDE should detect it and mark the variable as unused. This is probably the most important point.
Optionally, it allows me to use type annotations, but I can live without this.

So far I'm using class because it fulfills 1 and 2, but I've also tried @dataclass, NamedTuple, etc. All of them work perfect for 1 and 2. My problem is with 3.
No matter the linter, type checker, etc. I use, unused class attributes are not deteced as such, for obvious reasons.
Is there any way I can have a namespace, with attributes which can reference other attributes within the namespace (so, no SimpleNamespace), and which IDEs will detect unused attributes?
My IDE of choice is Visual Studio Code, but I assume that any solution working for some IDE will work for mine, too, since most of them use pylint, Pyright, Ruff, etc.

Why not use ordinary variables in a module?

In addition to @Barmar s comment: you can import ... as my_namespace. There you have your namespace

Barmar,  Wombatz, I already tried your suggestion (thanks anyway) but unfortunately unused variables in imported modules are never marked as unused, at least I haven't found how. And it is reasonable: MOST of the symbols in a module are not used when the module is imported, marking them all would clutter the linter report. In my tests, unused symbols in a module are marked as unused ONLY when those symbols are not used WITHIN the module. When the module is imported, all symbols seem to be ignored even when the linter is used in the most strict manner.
